# How to join from one joined table to another table in snowflake

Tags: mysql, sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to create one snowflake view using multiple tables.
I understand that FROM...JOIN statements can combine multiple tables.

When I would like to join from one table that already has a join from another table, what is the best way to write a script?
In this case, from Table 3, Table 4 and Table 5 are joined.  The Table 3 is joined from Table 1.

[image]

Comment: Please clarify. From the diagram you can see that Table 4 joins with Table 3 and Table 5 joins with Table 3. What is your question?

Comment: @MajaF. Sorry, my question was not clear.  I wanted to know if I needed to have FROM...JOIN... statements twice (First JOIN...FROM.. statement for Table 1,2,3.  Second JOIN...FROM... statement for Table 3,4,5).  Or I only needed one FROM...JOIN... statement.  Or if there is a better way to do this.

Comment: is this question about snowflake db or mysql db?

Answer (score 3):

Your question is not clear, but normally all the tables are `joined` as follows

```
select *
from table1 t1
join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.table1_ID
join table3 t3 on t1.id = t3.table1_ID
join table4 t4 on t3.id = t4.table3_ID
join table5 t5 on t3.id = t5.table3_ID
```

---

Your data is not clear what kind of data you need, but it depends on your needs, what information you need with what combination of tables.

```
with cte1 as (
   select * 
   from table1 t1 
   join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.table1_ID 
   join table3 t3 on t1.id = t3.table1_ID 
 ),
cte2 as ( 
     select * 
     from table3 t3 
     join table4 t4 on t3.id = t4.table3_ID 
     join table5 t5 on t3.id = t5.table3_ID) 
select t123.column1, t345.column2 
from cte1 join cte2 on cte1.id = cte2.id
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions and sorry my question was not clear.
I wanted to know if I needed to have FROM...JOIN... statements twice (First JOIN...FROM.. statement for Table 1,2,3. Second JOIN...FROM... statement for Table 3,4,5). Or I only needed one FROM...JOIN... statement. Or if there is a better way to do this.

Comment: Do you know how to create a Common Table Expression (CTE) in the view to make sub table?
I'm not familiar with CTE, but is this how you do it?

create or replace table t123 as
with cte1 as (
select *
from table1 t1
join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.table1_ID
join table3 t3 on t1.id = t3.table1_ID)

create or replace table t345 as
with cte2 as (
select *
from table3 t3
join table4 t4 on t3.id = t4.table3_ID
join table5 t5 on t3.id = t5.table3_ID)

create or replace view V_12345 as
select t123.column1, t345.column2
from t123
join t345 on t123.id = t345.id

Comment: It all depends on your data and the output you want

Answer (score 1):

Meysam answer is very valid, but I see there is more questions at hand.

[Edit] This answer is mostly general, but also focused on the Snowflake-cloud-data-platform tag perspective.

Normally you can have a single block of SELECT and there all the TABLES in the FROM JOIN zone, and all the WHERE's you like, in modern form the WHERE's that belong to the JOINS and not filters, are put on the ON, thus Meysam's answer.

```
SELECT 
    t1.thing,
    t2.other_thing,
    t4.extra_detail,
    t5.one_last_thing
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2 
   ON t1.id = t2.table1_ID
JOIN table3 t3 
   ON t1.id = t3.table1_ID
JOIN table4 t4 
   ON t3.id = t4.table3_ID
JOIN table5 t5 
   ON t3.id = t5.table3_ID
```

Now you mention a CTE which could be done on the table3 chain if there was merit like so:

```
WITH table_3_sub_chain_cte_of_merit AS (
    SELECT 
        t3.table1_ID
        t4.extra_detail,
        t5.one_last_thing
    FROM table3 t3 
    JOIN table4 t4 
       ON t3.id = t4.table3_ID
    JOIN table5 t5 
       ON t3.id = t5.table3_ID
)
SELECT 
    t1.thing,
    t2.other_thing,
    cte3.extra_detail,
    cte3.one_last_thing
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2 
   ON t1.id = t2.table1_ID
JOIN table_3_sub_chain_cte_of_merit cte3 
   ON t1.id = cte3.table1_ID
```

OR the CTE sub expression can be moved into a sub-select, if that had merit, like so:

```
SELECT 
    t1.thing,
    t2.other_thing,
    cte3.extra_detail,
    cte3.one_last_thing
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2 
   ON t1.id = t2.table1_ID
JOIN (
    SELECT 
        t3.table1_ID
        t4.extra_detail,
        t5.one_last_thing
    FROM table3 t3 
    JOIN table4 t4 
       ON t3.id = t4.table3_ID
    JOIN table5 t5 
       ON t3.id = t5.table3_ID
)cte3 
   ON t1.id = cte3.table1_ID
```

Now the interesting part, *merit*, why would we be doing these things.

The first version should meet your needs just fine if you want to just get some value off each table and move on. But if you are doing some complex filters on `table3` and below, or you are doing some expensive aggregation on the `table3` and below, but those result are match many times to `table1`, then doing the work in a CTE or sub-query makes sense.

Now why might you use the CTE over the subquery, the simple answer for the code given they are the same. But if you joined `table1` and `table3` multiple times, because you are calculated daily costs, weekly costs, and monthly costs, then build the costs once (in a CTE), and then joining those results can save a lot of time. But at the same time, sometimes CTE's can slow things down, as what might seem the "expensive code" is mostly free once the other work is taken into account, and thus I have seen code run faster on Snowflake doing a large aggregation three times in sub-selects as it removes the synchronization cost between the data paths, and the remote data read was the same bottle neck under both.

On the other hand sometime CTE's make reading the code cleaner, as you get to name the expression something meaningful, and then use an alias, so the SQL is more readable, but the intent is captured. And Snowflake optimizer rewrites the SQL anyways, some they can and are often the same. So helping humans is more value.

On other databases there optimizers can be helped by the order of the joins, and them being nested (or so I have been told) but I have not read/witnessed that on snowflake, but have spent days rewriting SQL to have it have the "same execution plan" in the other form.

But where CTE's shine can be in really large (hundreds of lines of SQL) in pushing filters to where you want them, to avoid really large data reads, and full table processing only to have that pruned. This sort of thing is spot able in the query profiler, but 10 billion rows going  between blocks for many steps only to hit a filter later in the pipeline and 5 thousand coming out.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to join exactly in the relation hierarchy you have listed such as

```
select
      t1.*,
      t2.whatever,
      t3.whatever3,
      t4.whatever4,
      t5.whatever5
   from
      table1 t1
         join table2 t2
            on t1.t2id = t2.id
         join table3 t3
            on t1.t3id = t3.id
            join table4 t4
               on t3.t4id = t4.id
            join table5 t5
               on t3.t5id = t5.id
```

So, what is the confusion